# Use mysqli_store_result by default

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have been reading up on `mysqli_store_result` and I don't understand why this is an opt-in and not an opt-out. According to the manual I should not use this for memory-hefty operations, but given I only fetch maybe 50-100 rows of text at a time (usually), I come to the conclusion that I should always use it, yet I must explicitly call it for every single query. This seems weird to me. I say this because it indicates to me that I have misunderstood something.

As far as I understand; if you read 100 rows and use `while ($stmt->fetch())` you are actually sending 100 read-next-requests to MySQL over the network (assuming web and DB are on different machines). If you use `mysqli_store_result` you send only one request and loop the result set on the webserver. Why would I not always do this? What am I missing?

And a subquestion: Does this have something to do with my MySQL status variable "handler read next" being very high, and would store_result help?

Comment: imo, I am not sure about the 'over the network' part of you question. The PHP script runs on the sever that the database is on normally. I suspect that the  the network overhead between PHP and the database engine is not significant. i.e .I tend to think of the 100 fetches as slow function calls. Also, the data will also have been buffered by the database engine. So there isn't a lot of work for either side to do to fetch the data.

Comment: The PHP script runs on the webserver, not on the database server. These are usually only the same host if the application is not scaled to any noteworthy size. I did some simple tests and cannot measure any difference between storing the result or not, so perhaps I should just leave this alone. Now I just don't see what purpose it serves.

Comment: point taken about  large databases

Answer (score 1):

> why this is an opt-in and not an opt-out.

Well, I can try to answer (or, at least, to speculate) *why* it is so.

Mysqli, like most of PHP, is just a thin wrapper over C functions. So thin that it doesn't add anything on its own. And the underlying C API, in turn, provides only basic functionality, leaving all the improvements on the implementation. And as you cannot "undo" getting the resultset on the client side, it seems logical that this is an opt-in by default.

It is interesting, though, why for `mysqli_query()` the buffered mode is turned on by default, but for prepare/execute it is not.

> yet I must explicitly call it for every single query.

Come on! is it the *only* thing you have to call for the every single query? What about *calling* bind_param, bind_result, execute()? You see, mysqli is all about calling the most basic API functions. So, in a way, calling `store_result()` is rather logical.

Given all that, I think that the only conclusion you can come to is that you are supposed to write your wrapper on top of mysqli, or you can use PDO, which is indeed a wrapper, with almost all required functionality already implemented.

Comment: Yes, obviously I need to call more than one thing per query, but all the other functions are either dependent on timing (execute/fetch) or related to the specific query (bind/prepare). I would find it reasonable to be able to globally (say, per connection) enable buffered reading.

Comment: then you should try PDO :)

Answer (score -1):

Actually, you may-or-may-not be issuing "100 requests." PHP is talking to a MySQL interface-layer which, in turn, is talking to the database.  (But you *can* observe the traffic, say by using "WireShark" or other equally-wonderous TCP/IP-sniffing tools ...)

However, having said that, what I wound up doing ... after encountering some "frankly, very strange" peculiarities ... was to fetch the entire result-set into an array, then close the statement-handle. My logic then doles-out the rows from that array. *"Less filling, tastes great."*

I had ... *issues* ... with `mysqli_store_result`, which I never did fully figure out. I therefore abandoned it, found an equally satisfactory way that *did* work (namely: "store it into a PHP array ..."), and moved on.

Comment: Can you elaborate (perhaps with code?) on the "fetch the entire result-set into an array" I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: to use mysqli_fetch_array() you either have to use store_result in the form of get_result, or use mysqli_query instead of prepared statements. which makes your musings rather irrelevant or self-contradicting.

Comment: Dunno ... it works, right now, for me! With prepared statements!

Comment: you are using get_result() then, which does the same buffering as store_result(). so your answer should read as "get a regular mysqli result via get_result" and moved on.